# optimize python code for memory efficiency

Tags: python, memory, numpy, reshape

I have a python code as follow:

```
import numpy as np

sizes = 2000
array1 = np.empty((sizes, sizes, sizes, 3), dtype=np.float32)
for i in range(sizes):
    array1[i, :, :, 0] = 1.5*i
    array1[:, i, :, 1] = 2.5*i
    array1[:, :, i, 2] = 3.5*i

array2 = array1.reshape(sizes*sizes*sizes, 3)

#do something with array2

array3 = array2.reshape(sizes*sizes*sizes, 3)
```

I would want to optimize this code for memory efficient but I have no idea. Could I use "numpy.reshape" by a more memory efficient way?

Comment: Reshape would not make your program more memory efficient. In your case, you seem to have 3*size^3 float elements. Reshape would change the shape of the matrix, but the number of elements, and consequently the memory they take up, would remain the same. However, each value in you matrix appears size^2 times. The point of creating such a 4D matrix is not clear. What do you want to use it for ??

Answer (score 1):

I think your code is already memory efficient.

When possible, `np.reshape` returns a view of the original array. That is so in this case and therefore `np.reshape` is already as memory efficient as can be.

Here is how you can tell `np.reshape` is returning a view:

```
import numpy as np
# Let's make array1 smaller; it won't change our conclusions
sizes = 5
array1 = np.arange(sizes*sizes*sizes*3).reshape((sizes, sizes, sizes, 3))

for i in range(sizes):
    array1[i, :, :, 0] = 1.5*i
    array1[:, i, :, 1] = 2.5*i
    array1[:, :, i, 2] = 3.5*i

array2 = array1.reshape(sizes*sizes*sizes, 3)
```

Note the value of `array2` at a certain location:

```
assert array2[0,0] == 0
```

Change the corresponding value *in `array1`*:

```
array1[0,0,0,0] = 100
```

Note that the value of `array2` changes.

```
assert array2[0,0] == 100
```

Since `array2` changes due to a modification of `array1`, you can conclude that `array2` is a view of `array1`. Views share the underlying data. Since there is no copy being made, the reshape is memory efficient.

`array2` is already of shape `(sizes*sizes*sizes, 3)`, so this reshape does nothing.

```
array3 = array2.reshape(sizes*sizes*sizes, 3)
```

Finally, the assert below shows `array3` was also affected by the modification made to `array1`. So that proves conclusively that `array3` is also a view of `array1`.

```
assert array3[0,0] == 100
```

Answer (score 0):

So really your problem depends on what you are doing with the array. You are currently storing a large amount of redundant information. You could keep 0.15% of the currently stored information and not lose anything.

For instance, if we define the following three one dimensional arrays

```
a = np.linspace(0,(size-1)*1.5,size).astype(np.float32)
b = np.linspace(0,(size-1)*2.5,size).astype(np.float32)
c = np.linspace(0,(size-1)*3.5,size).astype(np.float32)
```

We can create any minor entry (i.e. entry in the fastest rotating axis) in your `array1`:

```
In [235]: array1[4][3][19] == np.array([a[4],b[3],c[19]])
Out[235]: array([ True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
```

The use of this all depends on what you are doing with the array, as it will be less performant to remake `array1` from `a`,`b` and `c`. However, if you are nearing the limits of what your machine can handle, sacrificing performance for memory efficiency may be a necessary step. Also moving `a`,`b` and `c` around will have a much lower overhead than moving `array1` around.